# is there a framework like EventKit for android?

Tags: android

I developed a calendar for iPhone. I used EventKit and it was so useful.

so, I am wondering is there a framework like EventKit for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use calendar provider
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html